# Adjective for "nonbinding, advisory"

Tags: single-word-requests

The legislation recommends, but does not require, that women make up at least 40% of the board. The legislation is ___________.

I think there's a perfect word for this, but it eludes me at the moment.

Comment: Indicative (as opposed to definitive)?

Comment: I think you had it in your title; I'd use "advisory".

Comment: It's a recommendation. By the way, is legislation the proper term? The appropriate adjective would be "not obligatory".

Comment: Since both *nonbinding* and *advisory* fit, other than this "tip of the tongue" feeling, what eliminates them?

Answer (score 1):

Four possible words come to my mind (all definitions are from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*):

> **aspirational** *adj* **1 a :** [characteristic of] a strong desire to achieve something high or great **b :** [related to] an object of such desire
>
> **hortative** adj giving exhortation [in the sense of "language intended to incite and encourage"] : ADVISORY
>
> **precatory** *adj* **:** expressing a wish
>
> **toothless** *adj* **1 :** having no teeth **2 a :** lacking in sharpness or bite **b :** lacking in means of enforcement or coercion : INEFFECTUAL

Which option seems most accurate depends on the precise circumstances surrounding the legislation and on how optimistic you happen to be feeling.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @brasshat, *advisory* seems to fit your need.

A related term, usually applied to judicial rather than legislative matters is *[obiter dictum](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obiter-dictum)*

> (law) an observation by a judge on some point of law not directly in issue in the case before him and thus neither requiring his decision nor serving as a precedent, but nevertheless of persuasive authority [*Collins*]

The term is often shortened to *dictum* and that is often used in the plural as *dicta*

Answer (score -2):

The legislation is 'conciliatory', in other words, any recommendation aimed at engendering conciliatory feelings or goodwill, rather than taking on the force of law.